# How to get context path in plain HTML?

Tags: html

I used to have a jsp page with some EL/JSTL Tags. Now I want to rewrite it in plain HTML and JavaScript (because it will be placed in a CMS).

The loading of my JavaScript fails, because I used to load it with something like this

```
<script
    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/external/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, I could try to hard code the real path, but I want a bit flexibility. So is there an equivalent of `pageContext.request.contextPath` in plain html?

Comment: use relative paths if you've stored the assets on your own server (`<base href="...">` might help, but isn't necessary), or full url's when loaded from an external source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps you. Try using a CDN:

```
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

It's faster, secure and doesn't need to be downloaded too. Also, you can use relative paths from the domain name, say:

```
<script
    src="/assets/external/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

The above works if you know where exactly the script resides.

Comment: Any reasons why this is voted down? Happy to correct it. `:)`

Comment: thank you, first one will help me to use the 'official' libraries  but I will try the second one for my own scripts

Comment: @Kinaeh Thanks.